# How to add babel captions to newfloat package environments?

Tags: captions, babel, newfloat

This minimal example, will produce the following PDF:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},
         name=Frame,within=chapter,listname=List of Frames]{board}

% \addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\boardname}{Quadro}}
% \addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listofboardsname}{Lista de Quadros}}

\newif\ifenglish\englishfalse
% \englishtrue
\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\ifenglish#1\else#2\fi}

\ifenglish
    \PassOptionsToPackage{language=english}{biblatex}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}
\else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{language=brazil}{biblatex}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{main=brazil,english,spanish,french}{babel}
\fi

\begin{document}

\section{\lang{English Section}{Seção em Português}}

    \listofboards*

    \lang{Section contents.}{Conteúdo da seção.}

    \begin{board}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{\lang{Subtitle}{Legenda}}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \lang{Content}{Conteúdo}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \fonte{\lang{Author}{Autor}}
    \end{board}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where the `captions` are mixed with English. If you uncomment the lines `\addto\captionsbrazil`, Latex will throw the error:

```
LaTeX Error: \listofboardsname undefined.
```

I had used something like `\addto\captionsbrazil` on this other issue [How to override command on my preamble, after its redefinition by my class with renewcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/482523/how-to-override-command-on-my-preamble-after-its-redefinition-by-my-class-with), and it fixed the problem. How can I use `\addto\captionsbrazil` with the `newfloat` package board environment I just created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading this question [The changes package and british babel: Undefined control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229594/the-changes-package-and-british-babel-undefined-control-sequence), I managed to fix it by:

1. Creating a command to hold the title of the list
2. Using that command to pass the title of the list to `DeclareFloatingEnvironment`
3. Using `\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listofboardsname}`

```latex
\newif\ifenglish\englishfalse

% \englishtrue
\newcommand{\lang}[2]{\ifenglish#1\else#2\fi}

\ifenglish
    \PassOptionsToPackage{language=english}{biblatex}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}
\else
    \PassOptionsToPackage{language=brazil}{biblatex}
    \PassOptionsToPackage{main=brazil,english,spanish,french}{babel}
\fi

\documentclass[12pt]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{newfloat}
\newcommand\listofboardsname{List of Frames}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=Frame,
        within=chapter,listname=\listofboardsname]{board}

\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\boardname}{Quadro}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listofboardsname}{Lista de Quadros}}

\begin{document}

\section{\lang{English Section}{Seção em Português}}

    \listofboards

    \lang{Section contents.}{Conteúdo da seção.}

    \begin{board}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{\lang{Subtitle}{Legenda}}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|}
    \hline
    \lang{Content}{Conteúdo}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \fonte{\lang{Author}{Autor}}
    \end{board}

\end{document}
```

---

References:

1. [Why doesn't LaTeX hyphenate words containing accents, e.g. "développement"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183808/why-doesnt-latex-hyphenate-words-containing-accents-e-g-d%C3%A9veloppement)
2. [Remove List of [newfloat] from TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176418/remove-list-of-newfloat-from-toc)

Comment: There is already a predefined command for the "List of Frames", but it's not called `\listofboardsname` but `\listboardname` (since the existing one for the "List of Figures" is called `\listfigurename` and not `\listoffiguresname`). So the code in your question works fine with this replacement.

Comment: ...unfortunately this part is missing in the `newfloat` documentation, I just added a ticket for that: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/51